# How can i use Auth::user() in App\Exceptions\Handler class in Laravel 5.7?

Tags: laravel, authentication, exception, laravel-5.7

I cant check if user is logged in. I need to load different error pages according to Request::segment() and Auth::check().
At that point Auth::check() is FALSE and Auth::user() is NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class` to the global `$middleware` array in `App/Http/Kernel.php`.

Comment: Auth::check() is working but Auth::user() always returns null.